# Why does using a single HTTPClient, rather than making a new client per request, drastically slow down my API?

Tags: asp.net, api, dotnet-httpclient

I am building an gateway for another API with .Net core's web API 2. The other service I am interacting with has 5 functionalities, with post/get commands required for each functionality. In an attempt to improve high latency, I made sure that rather than creating a new HTTP client in a using statement for each request, I would use a singleton HTTP client. I noticed after this implementation, my requests took much longer.

```
- Post request
    * 800 ms, when creating new http client with each request
    * 2000 ms, when using single http client
- Get request
    * 1200 ms, when creating new http client with each request
    * 2200 ms, when using single http client
```

Comment: Have you tried HttpClienttFactory ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests

Comment: Can you show your code which is doing the call? Are you using `await` or are you blocking with `.Result()`?

Comment: Please do provide code snippet. Also, can you update on how many times you executed the code to arrive at above result. My observation is contrary to above. Also, creating a new HttpClient every time puts up additional load on both processor and memory

Comment: I found out I was awaiting on calls that had .result already in them... after removing that it appears I finally see a performance boost.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is not enough information in your question, to answer this specifically

But in general, its recommended to use a single static HttpClient

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests

*HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and reused throughout the life of an application. Instantiating an HttpClient class for every request will exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy loads.*

.Net core supports HttpClientFactory for managing this, which I would profile for your scenario

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately just ran out of battery on my laptop so I can’t provide code snippets. I’m basically trying to follow microsoft’s sample of a gateway down to a T (particularly this repo: https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/tree/dev/src/ApiGateways/Web.Bff.Shopping/aggregator). In this case I have a controller, which uses a service to send requests through a single readonly HTTP client.